# How to handle file upload using Sahi testing tool for angular js application?

Tags: angularjs, file, file-upload, sahi

We have a customer using angular js application and have to support testing of that via Sahi.I have tried some Sahi APIs of setFile to automate the file upload but its not working..Do anyone have idea on how to use those APIs for Angular applications?

Comment: Angular applications are no different in terms of how file upload works. If you can link a sample where you can't upload a file, that would be useful. Otherwise my implementation of file upload works fine with Sahi.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native function for uploading the file.
Use _setFileUpload($element, $path,)

$element will be the _file("upload.. ") object. 
$path will be the path where the file to be uploaded is kept.